# UK Postcode area in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, postal-code

Im trying to extract the first part of a UK postcode using SQL (Redshift)
For example, **BT28 8YT** should return **BT** - so basically the first one or two alphabetical characters, but it should not return a number. I'm finding the UK Govt regex a little tough to work with!

Heres what I have so far but I'm struggling with what regex function I should be using, so redshift is throwing syntax errors.

```
[Amazon]() Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "REGEXP";

SELECT 
    IF((left(orders.customer_postcode,2) REGEXP '[0-9]') = 0, left(orders.customer_postcode,2), left(orders.customer_postcode,1)) AS "orders.postcode_area"
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postcode area will always be one or two letters followed by a number.

It looks like you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to do this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

```
select regexp_substr(customer_postcode,'^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}') from orders
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also user [SIMILAR TO](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-similar-to.html) to do this. For example for the WC postcode you can use:
 `postcode similar to 'WC[1-2][A-Z][[:space:]][A-Z0-9]{3}'` etc.